A Child Flexbox elements height keeps growing larger than parents flexbox containers height
I have one horizontal flexbox container that has 2 child vertical flexbox containers, like the following:


<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 1; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0;">
        <div style="height: 500px; background-color: red;">
            Large element with dynamic height. Scrollbar should appear when height is more than blue box.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;">
            Small element with fixed height
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



With regard to width: The first child (the one on the left) I want to grow horizontally so it fills most of the width, while the second child I want to shrink to just fit its contents. Hence, I placed a flex-grow: 1; on the first child.
With regard to height: I want the height of the parent to fit tightly to the content of the second child since the items in the second child will be a fixed height. The first child will be a table with a dynamic number of rows so I'd like the first child to have a height no larger than the height of its parent and if the first child's height is too large then I get a scrollbar. Hence, I placed a min-height: 0; overflow-y: auto;
The Problem: As the first child grows larger I never get the scrollbar to appear (even once the first child's height grows larger than the second child's height). No matter what, the parent's height is always the larger of its children's heights.


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Use display: grid; and set height: 0; min-height: 100%; for the left <div>.


<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;">
  <div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 0; min-height: 100%;">
    <div style="height: 500px; background-color: red;">
      Large element with dynamic height. Scrollbar should appear when height is more than blue box.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;">
      Small element with fixed height
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



If you know the height of the right <div>, set the parent to the desired height:


<div style="display: flex; height: 200px;">
  <div style="overflow-y: auto; flex: auto;">
    <div style="height: 500px; background-color: red;">
      Large element with dynamic height. Scrollbar should appear when height is more than blue box.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div style="width: 200px; flex: none; background-color: blue; min-height:100%;">
      Small element with fixed height
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




The second child elements height is not known. I just set its height to 200px in the example for demonstration. I'll edit the question to clarify that. So I can't set the parent to 200px since I don't know the height.

Probably not the most perfect solution, but it might work: the content of a first child can be wrapped in an additional absolutely positioned scrollable container.
It must be stretched to fit the first child (the one on the left) completely.


.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.second-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.second-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="first-child">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="content">
        Large element with dynamic height. Scrollbar should appear when height is more than blue box.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
    <div class="second-content">
      Small element with fixed height
    </div>
  </div>
</div>






* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent-section {
    height: 100vh; 
    max-height: 50vh; /* and you can set a max-height */
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 4px solid green;
}

.parent-section main {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 4px solid blue;
}

.parent-section aside {
    width: 300px;
    border: 4px solid red;
}
<section class="parent-section">

    <main>
        <ul>
            <li data-repeat='200'>item</li>
        </ul>
    </main>

    <aside>
        <p>Small element with fixed height</p>
    </aside>

</section>



<!-- ignore this -->
<script src="https://peprojects.dev/scripts/repeat.js"></script>



There are many many ways you could do this. Here's one. I'm using section, main, aside for readability here. But I suspect thinking about it as the smaller side is determining height - is the wrong way to go. We'd have to know more about the desired final outcome - instead of how you're trying to get there (to give you the best advice). And I'd probably use Grid for this these days.
flexbox: https://codepen.io/perpetual-education/pen/XWwrOwY?editors=1100
grid: https://codepen.io/perpetual-education/pen/NWVKJPp?editors=1100
.parent-section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 200px;
    /*                   fill   sidebar */
}

